# same meaning of "10 percent of gross sales" by putting gross sales in front?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

Sometimes I'm in a situation where I have to give more detail such as a specific number only after I speak a thing.

For example as written in the title, when I speak about a gross sales of a company, I might say "The tax is calculated from the gross sales" then realize I want to give more information about how much the tax is calculated from the gross sales. Is it just okay to add the information at the last like "The tax is calculated from the gross sales, about 10 percent"?

Is there any way to convey the meaning? What I ultimately like to convey is "The tax is calculated from about 10 percent of the gross sales"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your own question!

> The tax is calculated from about 10 percent of the gross sales

For the previous sentence,

> The tax is calculated from the gross sales, about 10 percent

It is slightly unclear 10 percent of **what**, it could be 10% tax or 10% gross sales, so its better to use the sentence you gave last. Just to clarify, it is still *useable*, but the first one is still better.

If you want to talk about the gross sales first then the 10 percent, best is to use:

> The tax is calculated from the gross sales, around/about 10 percent of the latter

The latter in this case referring to the gross sales, as the 2 things are the "tax" and the "gross sales"

A slightly less vague one, is:

> The tax is calculated from the gross sales, around/about 10 percent of it

Comment: Hey, what I'm asking is substitution of "10 percent of the gross sales". If I talk "the gross sales" first, then how should I add the informationf of "10 percent"?

Comment: @DonghoonLEE I added it in, does my answer help?

Comment: Perfect answer.